# editing href in Orchard.ContentManagement.ContentItem

Tags: c#, razor, orchardcms

I am trying to integrate disqus comment counts in bloq summary.

```
@{ 
    Orchard.ContentManagement.ContentItem contentItem = Model.ContentPart.ContentItem;
    string bodyHtml = Model.Html.ToString();
    var body = new HtmlString(Html.Excerpt(bodyHtml, 8000).ToString().Replace(Environment.NewLine, "</p>" + Environment.NewLine + "<p>"));

}
<p>@body @Html.ItemDisplayLink(T("more").ToString(), contentItem)</p>
```

so i need to concatinate #disqus_thread to the href of the contentItem link.

I cant use any plugin for implementing disqus. How can i edit the href?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking to get the display url of a content item, us the Url helper, e.g.:

`<a href="@Url.ItemDisplayUrl(contentItem)">@T("more")</a>`

Now you have full control over the href, allowing you to append whatever querystring parameter you need.